# Reading Linux Repositories from Third Party

Tags: java, linux, repository, yum, apt

I am trying to create an app that would be able to generate kickstart scripts (along other things) and for one of the things to add was a list of packages you can install (obviously wont display them all, but will have a function to allow you to know if the package is available).
The problem I am finding is finding any documentation on how yum/apt read their repositories. 
Does anyone know on where to find documentation on this sort of thing or if there is an open sourced app that does a simular thing (reading the repository that is)

Comment: I am not getting your question - instead of re-implementing the protocol that the yum/apt clients are using when talking to a repository; shouldn't you instead call those tools to make the queries you need? In other words: if the yum server gives answers in a certain language, why do you want to speak that language; instead of have the yum client do the talking on behalf of you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APT and YUM repositories have different internal metadata formats:

- APT: Can be parsed with libapt, or your own tools. It is pretty straightforward as the metadata format isn't too complicated.
- YUM: Can be parsed with any XML library; the metadata is stored as XML and easily parsed with any XML library for any major programming language.

You can learn more about [YUM repository metadata in this blog post](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/07/20/yum-repository-internals/). You can learn more about [APT repository metadata in this blog post](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/08/04/apt-repository-internals/).

Comment: Thanks alot, this is the sort of information i was looking for. I knew YUM was xml but wanted to get APT out the way before trying to reverse engineer the xml. Again many thanks and to the sources as well.